# Vertical crack in exterior wall - visible on both sides

Tags: walls, crack

I have a nearly 3 year old house that has developed a crack in an exterior wall.  The crack is vertical, runs from first story ceiling to floor, and is visible on both the inside and outside.

Is this something I should be concerned about or is it likely due to settling of the house?

I have included photos.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be from settling or from when it was built and took this long to crack the stucco and paint finish. At this point I'd monitor it to see if it gets worse. I would be proactive and get some Siliconizer and brush it on both sides of the crack to prevent any moisture from seeping through the crack and seams of the block.

Comment: On a new home probably settling, but sealing is a good idea.